# I am trying Jquery Ui Autocomplete with Images. Its not bringing any response

Tags: php, jquery, image, user-interface, autocomplete

I want to get a response of User Details with their Names and Profile Images:
**For Example.** Facebook is using the Same thing i am trying to do. That is, When you type a Name in Search of Facebook. It returns a User with his Profile Picture and His Name in the Drop Down, When you click a specific User it redirects you to his Profile. Same is the thing i am trying to do. And i am not getting any response from Php page too. No jquery Errors in Console.

**Here is my JS code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#data_images").autocomplete("user_data.php", {
  width: 320,
  max: 4,
  highlight: false,
  scroll: true,
  scrollHeight: 300,
  formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
    return "<img src='images/" + value + "'/> " + value.split(".")[0];
  },
  formatResult: function(data, value) {
    return value.split(".")[0];
  }
});
</script>
```

**Here is my Html Code**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="data_images" />
</div>
```

Please give me a proper solution.

Comment: Please provide more details.  You cannot possibly expect us to understand completely what you're trying to do with a one-sentence description.  What does it do now? Any javascript errors? What does your php return? Is the php function working properly?

Comment: Please check my Post now. I have added proper details now.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI Autocomplete expects data from the server in a certain format so we cannot tell what is wrong with your code without the PHP source code in `user_data.php`.

If you cannot post this, can you at least give us a data sample of exactly what it is sending back to jQuery?